# Is there any advantage to preloading fonts directly before or after the stylesheet that references them?

Tags: html, css, fonts, preload

I have a `fonts.css` stylesheet that defines `@font-face`s for four webfonts, for example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'example';
    src: url('/fonts/example-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/example-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    font-stretch: normal;
}
```

I would like the fonts to load as soon as possible to minimise the FOUC. I have a link to the stylesheet in my page `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.css" />
```

**Is there any advantage (in terms of how quickly the fonts will be available)to preloading the fonts either directly before or after this <`link`>?**

So either:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.css" />
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/fonts/examplebook-webfont.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
...
```

Or

```
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="/fonts/examplebook-webfont.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.css" />
```

Note:

- We use http2

Comment: Have you done some measurements already in your developer tools’ network tab?
Do you want to know whether the order of those to links makes a difference? Or whether the `preload` makes a difference?
If you use HTTP/2, you could use a server push as well.

Comment: I've done some measurement, but I'm interested in what the received wisdom is from a technical point of view. I'm interested in knowing:
1. Does preloading the fonts make a difference?
2. If so, does the order of make a difference?

Comment: With an empty cache, I’m assuming? And in this setup, or in a more realistic setup where the CSS referencing the fonts might be way bigger?

Comment: Yes with an empty cache. Rest of my CSS is inlined (using Gatsby with Styled components), but I guess it would be interesting for others to know the effect of more CSS in the same file.